# I want to implement dismissible ads (similar to the Pandora app) on iOS. Any suggestions or frameworks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, popup, ads

So, I'd like to put ads in my app which is nearing release (never done anything with ads before) and I want to do it in a non-intrusive manner.  I'm looking for help to come up with a decent non-hackneyed way of accomplishing this.

What I'm looking for is something similar to banner ads in Pandora. Like this (though not nearly as tall): [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78jUx.jpg)

If you can't look at the image: in Pandora, when a banner ad pops up, it has a little X in the corner.  Pressing the X dismisses the ad for a few minutes.  The banner ad floats over content if not dismissed, just above the UITabBar.

Are there any frameworks to do something like this?  If not...how would I go about doing it?

My first instinct would be to create a UIView for the ad with a button in the corner that removes it from its superview, and the ad itself.  Then add it to the UITabBar my app has.  But this feels very sloppy- I am just too green to think of a better way to accomplish it.

What's the normal way to do something like this?

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: @Andy, that's not a very useful answer...UIKit is a very big framework.  Any tips on what sort of mechanisms or design patterns I should use?

Comment: Well you can create a separate UIWindow and place your banner there, this is the safest option and this is how lots of HUD libraries work.

Comment: The second option is to add custom view UIView directly to view controller. This is less reliable as will participate in the same view hierarchy as other views of application.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want because from your example, the ad is kind of very intrusive. There is a diff between automated ads that pull from nowhere randomly and ads those that can be placed / triggered manually in the right place (see native advertising like twitter)